# How would I print a float to the decimal place of a user specified value in python

Tags: python

My code,

```
print ("Welcome to the Imperial to Metric converter")

choice = int(input("For Fahrenheit to Celsius press 1, Feet to Meters press 2, Pounds to Kilograms press 3: "))

if choice != 1 and 2 and 3:
  print ("Choose a valid function")
else:
  value = float(input("Select the value you wish to convert: "))
  def convert(value):
    if choice == 1:
      return (value - 32) * (5/9)
    elif choice == 2:
      return value / 3.2808
    elif choice == 3:
      return value  / 2.2046

  print ("%.2f" %(float(convert(value))))
```

This is what I have so far and would like to print out the answer to whatever decimal place the user put the value as, say they wanted to convert `42.78` Fahrenheit I would want to give the answer as `xx.xx`

Comment: Replace `if choice != 1 and 2 and 3` with `if choice not in (1, 2, 3)` because the former doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @CoryKramer Actually, `if choice not in {1, 2, 3}` would be optimal.

Comment: Really, it makes no difference on data of that size ^.

Comment: `if not (1 <= choice <= 3):`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `round()` which would allow you to specify the decimal places easier:

```
>>> round(1.23234, 2)
1.23
```

---

So, to apply this to your code, you would need to store their input as a `string` first so you could work out how many to round to, and then round at the end:

```
print ("Welcome to the Imperial to Metric converter")

choice = int(input("For Fahrenheit to Celsius press 1, Feet to Meters press 2, Pounds to Kilograms press 3: "))

if choice not in (1, 2, 3):
  print ("Choose a valid function")
else:
  s = input("Select the value you wish to convert: ")
  value = float(s)
  def convert(value):
    if choice == 1:
      return (value - 32) * (5/9)
    elif choice == 2:
      return value / 3.2808
    elif choice == 3:
      return value  / 2.2046

 print(round(float(convert(value)), len(s.split(".")[1])))
```

which when I entered:

```
count <== 1
value <== 567.123
```

gave the right result of:

```
297.291
```

Comment: Nice, but maybe use `s.partition(".")[2]`, otherwise it will fail if the input is an integer value, i.e. has no `.`.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to preserve the user's precise value, including the number of digits beyond the decimal point, I'd use `decimal.Decimal` and especially `decimal.Decimal.quantize()`.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def convert(value):
    if choice == 1:
        return (value - 32) * 5/9
    elif choice == 2:
        return value / 32808 * 10000
    elif choice == 3:
        return value / 22046 * 10000

choice = 1
value = Decimal(input("Select the value you wish to convert: "))
print("%s" % (convert(value).quantize(value)))
```

Results:

```
$ python3 x.py 
Select the value you wish to convert: 32
0
$ python3 x.py 
Select the value you wish to convert: 32.000
0.000
$
```

Note, however, that you'll have to rewrite each of your formulas. You can't multiply a `Decimal` by a `float`.